# How to open a link on a new tab using WebGL/C# through Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Currently opening a link through my game opens the link in the very same interface. I want it to open on a new tab. I tried researching plugins and whatnot so that a .jslib file interacts with the Unity project, but am having issues with that too. I'm new to this interaction so I'm also having problems finding the Plugin Inspector itself.

Currently, my code does this:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Application.OpenURL("www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

So this opens the link on the same browser. I'm trying to make it so when the user hits the return key, they open that link on to a new browser.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say a new browser, I meant a new tab ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One correct way is using .jslib file

Assets/plugins/plugin.jslib

```
var plugin = {
    OpenNewTab : function(url)
    {
        url = Pointer_stringify(url);
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    },
};
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, plugin);
```

Your C# script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class OpenURL : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void OpenNewTab(string url);

    public void openIt(string url)
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
             OpenNewTab(url);
#endif
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            openIt("www.wateverurluwant.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current solution (since Unity 2019 or so) is the one Alienator5000 originally tried, with "Application.OpenURL".
It now opens your URL in a new tab. You can see more details on my response to [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569296/9903390).

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score -2):

Another solution in unity. You can still use `ExternalEval`, even if it is deprecated:

```
Application.ExternalEval("window.open('" + YourLink + "', '_blank')");
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a deprecated function when there is a working no deprecated alternative